# How is scipy.special.expi implemented?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I was using `scipy.special.expn` when I realized I could be using `expi` instead and it should be much faster, to judge from the Cephes code that I expected it would be based on. But switching from `expn` to `expi` made almost no difference in runtime.

This made me suspect that `expi` is implemented by an equivalent call to `expn` which does not take advantage of the simpler conditions in force for `expi`. But looking through the source code for scipy I am baffled as to how `expi` is implemented. I can find the C source for `expn` but not `expi`.

Can someone clarify how `expi` is implemented and/or where I can find the source for it?

Comment: Did you profile your code to make sure, that this function has costs which are high enough (compared to the rest)? ```expi``` seems to be implemented by calling Fortran-library-code [link](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2526df72e5d4ca8bad6e2f4b3cbdfbc33e805865/scipy/special/specfun_wrappers.h).

Comment: According to line_profiler, approximately 50% of the time is spent in the one line where `expi` is called.

Thanks for the link. I'm still having trouble connecting the dots between the header function declarations and the actual code.

Comment: The link above links to the name ```expi_wrap```, which is wrapped [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2526df72e5d4ca8bad6e2f4b3cbdfbc33e805865/scipy/special/specfun_wrappers.c#L188). You see, that function ```EIX``` is called which is defined in this **huge** fortran-code file [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/specfun/specfun.f#L5587). But this is also new territory for me and i can't explain to you why you are not observing a speedup. Maybe follow expn too and compare the functions. Of course you could always try your luck at scipy's mailing-list.

Comment: Perfect, that was just what I was looking for. The implementation is quite different, both from `expn` and from the Cephes implementation of `expi`. Thanks!